# how to get all threads pthread_t id of a process without gdb/pstack on linux

Tags: multithreading

I want to print all threads stack of one process, without pstack,gdb.  i want to use pthread_kill to send self defined signal to all threads, and use signal_handler to accept it and then print the current thread stack,
but the problem is how can i get all threads id?
I have already tried that: read subdirs under /proc/$pid/task, but that represents LWP thread, not pthread_t.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try to print all threads backtrace
if (DIR* dir = opendir("/proc/self/task")) {
  int thread_id;
  while (dirent* entry = readdir(dir)) {
    if (entry->d_name[0] == '.')
      continue;
    try {
      thread_id = std::stol(entry->d_name);
      ldout(m_cct, 1) << "send SIGUSR2 to " << thread_id << dendl;
      syscall(SYS_tgkill, getpid(), thread_id, SIGUSR2);
      t.sleep();
    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
      // pass
    }
  }
  closedir(dir);
}
```